# Dropbox Repository

Tags: repository, dropbox

I checked on linux.dropbox.com and the most recent repository is still Disco whose version apparently passed end of life and is not supported anymore.
Is it okay from a security point of view to continue using the desktop application?
Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with installing the `nautilus-dropbox` package?  As for your question, generally, you have to ask yourself the pros and cons of using something that is passed end of life.  After all, a piece of software might not get security updates but it's also possible that the software no longer needs software updates.  (I'm not saying Dropbox is such a program.)  We shouldn't keep thinking that software *needs* software updates because they we've given up on the possibility that software can never be correct...

Comment: Or just `dropbox` (multiverse repository)? Just open it to run the installer that installs the sync app, add the current repository for updates and integrates with Gnome DE.

Comment: Although it is labelled "Disco", the version is 2020.03.04 which is current as can be checked also from https://www.dropbox.com/install

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox is [well-integrated](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dropbox&searchon=names&suite=impish&section=all) with current Ubuntu desktop environments, depending on them you can proceed as follows:

- GNOME Shell

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
  ```
- MATE as in Ubuntu MATE

  ```
  sudo apt-get install caja-dropbox
  ```
- Xfce as in Xubuntu

  ```
  sudo apt-get install thunar-dropbox-plugin
  ```

then follow instructions on screen.